# Data Science Interview Question - Build a model to Predict the Class of the Output

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining

I recently attended an Interview and I was asked this question by the Interviewer.

> Question : There are 100 books, 90 of the books belong to category A and 10 of the books belong to category B. Build a model to make sure that the output is more than 90 percent. Explain Which model would you select and how would you evaluate the model output.

My answer was based on Naïve-Bayes as I believed it has got an unbalanced classifier and it is more related to the SPAM identifier technique.

Kindly share your thoughts.

Comment: What data about the books is available to the classifier?

Comment: @djma That was not a part of the question that he asked me. It was a kind of trap as you see the dataset, even if you classify all the books as Category A, you will still get the 90 percent as your accuracy. So, the answer that he was looking for is, How I will work with Imbalanced Classifier, how will I select my training and testing set ? Which model obviously will you choose and how would you evaluate that model accuracy?

Comment: I wouldn't say there's an "obvious model"... but for model accuracy there's always the tradeoff between precision and recall. If there's a specific preference, you'd use that. Otherwise, something like AUC is pretty standard.

Comment: @djma I think that point right there when you say that tradeoff between Precision and Recall solves this problem. So, if you just write that as an answer, I will mark it.

Comment: Logistic regression gives you a true probability.. That seems obvious model

Comment: I think this question is borderline (& maybe should be CW), but answerable. Indeed, it has an upvoted & accepted answer. I'm voting to leave open.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't say there's an "obvious model"... but for model accuracy there's always the tradeoff between precision and recall. If there's a specific preference, you'd use that. Otherwise, something like AUC is pretty standard.